# I got locked out of my vps, how do I proceed after I get it back in rescue mode?

Tags: ssh

I can no longer login to my vps. This is a brand new vps I created. This is what I did:

```
sudo vim sshd_config
```

In Authentication I have no for PermitRootLogin

I removed the hash for AuthorizedKeysFile

I made PasswordAuthentication to No

I did

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

I tried logging in to my vps again and I get this:

```
$ ssh user@<ip-address>
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

I did not create a passphrase and so I get this:

```
$ ssh user@<ip-address>
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa':
Permission denied (publickey)
```

I will be getting access back in rescue mode. I am going to go in and put PermitRootLogin back to yes.

How should I proceed going forward? Should I just create a new ssh key pair? I did notice the authorized_keys in my server match the id_rsa.pub on my local machine. Can I just delete them both to start all over again?